# How could we detect a dark matter particle?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, dark-matter, experimental-technique

If dark matter only interacts via gravity, how is detection of a dark matter particle proposed? Don't current particle detectors rely on the other (non-gravitational) interactions?

Comment: The wikipedia article on this is quite nice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Detection_of_dark_matter_particles

Comment: @ArturodonJuan So direct detection involves collisions with ordinary matter, which means I was wrong that dark matter interacts with ordinary matter only via gravity?

Comment: All we really know (after decades of investigation) is that dark matter doesn't interact electromagnetically (and also via the strong interaction). That leaves only the weak interaction and gravity. Models where, among other things, dark matter interacts via the weak interaction have stood the test of time and seem highly viable.

Comment: If dark matter is indeed in accord with, say, the WIMP hypothesis, then people who work in direct detection may detect them - specifically by measuring a highly-amplified signal resulting from a nuclear recoil on a target (due to an impinging WIMP) all made possible by weak interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by observation dark matter does not interact electromagnetically, and/or by the strong force, this leaves for a particle physics candidate for [dark matter](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/darmat.html) the [weakly  and gravitationaly](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/darmat.html) interacting ones.

> Two types of proposed constituents of the dark matter have been proposed and investigated, and have been given the labels WIMPS and MACHOS. WIMP is an acronym for weakly interacting massive particle and MACHO is an acronym for massive compact halo object. WIMPS would be new kinds of particles interacting by the weak interaction, and efforts have been made to observe them using techniques used for detecting neutrinos.

The neutrino interacts only weakly, and it was at some point a candidate, but its mass is too small to explain the effects in the galactic orbits which need that extra mass. Thus one is looking in particle theories for weakly interacting candidates, not discovered yet, expected from [supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) and other extensions of the standard model.